# Mark duplicates based on time difference between successive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are duplicated transactions in a bank dataframe(DF). ID is customer IDs. Duplicated transaction is a multi-swipe, where a vendor accidentally charges a customer's card multiple times within a short time span (2 minutes here).

```py
DF = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['111', '111', '111','111', '222', '222', '222', '333', '333', '333', '333','111'],'Dollar': [1,3,1,10, 25, 8, 25,9,20, 9, 9,10],'transactionDateTime': ['2016-01-08 19:04:50', '2016-01-29 19:03:55', '2016-01-08 19:05:50', '2016-01-08 20:08:50', '2016-01-08 19:04:50', '2016-02-08 19:04:50', '2016-03-08 19:04:50', '2016-01-08 19:04:50', '2016-03-08 19:05:53', '2016-01-08 19:03:20', '2016-01-08 19:02:15', '2016-02-08 20:08:50']})
DF['transactionDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['transactionDateTime'])

    ID  Dollar  transactionDateTime
0   111     1   2016-01-08 19:04:50
1   111     3   2016-01-29 19:03:55
2   111     1   2016-01-08 19:05:50
3   111     10  2016-01-08 20:08:50
4   222     25  2016-01-08 19:04:50
5   222     8   2016-02-08 19:04:50
6   222     25  2016-03-08 19:04:50
7   333     9   2016-01-08 19:04:50
8   333     20  2016-03-08 19:05:53
9   333     9   2016-01-08 19:03:20
10  333     9   2016-01-08 19:02:15
11  111     10  2016-02-08 20:08:50
```

I want to add a column to my dataframe, which recognizes the duplicated transactions (dollar amount of same customer ID should be the same, and transaction date time should be less than 2 minutes). Please consider the first transaction to be "normal".

```py
    ID  Dollar  transactionDateTime     Duplicated?
0   111     1   2016-01-08 19:04:50     No
1   111     3   2016-01-29 19:03:55     No
2   111     1   2016-01-08 19:05:50     Yes
3   111     10  2016-01-08 20:08:50     No
4   222     25  2016-01-08 19:04:50     No
5   222     8   2016-02-08 19:04:50     No
6   222     25  2016-03-08 19:04:50     No
7   333     9   2016-01-08 19:04:50     Yes
8   333     20  2016-03-08 19:05:53     No
9   333     9   2016-01-08 19:03:20     Yes
10  333     9   2016-01-08 19:02:15     No
11  111     10  2016-02-08 20:08:50     No
```

Comment: is dependent in ID too?

Comment: yes, customer ID should be the same.

Comment: Your data isn't sorted by transactionDateTime, so it doesn't looks like your output is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can `groupby` and `diff` to check whether the difference between successive transactions is less than 120 seconds:

```
df['Duplicated?'] = (df.sort_values(['transactionDateTime'])
                       .groupby(['ID', 'Dollar'], sort=False)['transactionDateTime']
                       .diff()
                       .dt.total_seconds()
                       .lt(120))
df

     ID  Dollar transactionDateTime  Duplicated?
0   111       1 2016-01-08 19:04:50        False
1   111       3 2016-01-29 19:03:55        False
2   111       1 2016-01-08 19:05:50         True
3   111     100 2016-01-08 20:08:50        False
4   222      25 2016-01-08 19:04:50        False
5   222       8 2016-02-08 19:04:50        False
6   222      25 2016-03-08 19:04:50        False
7   333       9 2016-01-08 19:04:50         True
8   333      20 2016-03-08 19:05:53        False
9   333       9 2016-01-08 19:03:20         True
10  333       9 2016-01-08 19:02:15        False
11  111     100 2016-02-08 20:08:50        False
```

Note that your data isn't sorted, so you must sort it first to get a meaningful result.

Comment: @P.J yes because your data isn't sorted, marking duplicates doesn't make sense unless you sort it first.

Comment: @P.J If you remove the `.sort_values` call, you get the output you have shown above. Which IMO is WRONG.

Comment: Yes, I need it sorted first. Thanks again.

Comment: @cs95 I believe you need to include the `Dollar` too in the groupby, inorder to consider it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
m=(DF.groupby('customerID')['transactionDateTime'].diff()/ np.timedelta64(1, 'm')).le(2)
DF['Duplicated?']=np.where((DF.Dollar.duplicated()&m),'Yes','No')
print(DF)
```

---

```
   customerID  Dollar transactionDateTime Duplicated?
0         111       1 2016-01-08 19:04:50          No
1         111       3 2016-01-29 19:03:55          No
2         111       1 2016-01-08 19:05:50         Yes
3         111     100 2016-01-08 20:08:50          No
4         222      25 2016-01-08 19:04:50          No
5         222       8 2016-02-08 19:04:50          No
6         222      25 2016-03-08 19:04:50          No
7         333       9 2016-01-08 19:04:50          No
8         333      20 2016-03-08 19:05:53          No
9         333       9 2016-01-08 19:03:20         Yes
10        333       9 2016-01-08 19:02:15         Yes
11        111     100 2016-02-08 20:08:50          No
```

Comment: I need to first sort times? for ID=333 the first happened 9$ is not a duplicated, but the second and third 9$ in order of time are duplicated.

Comment: @P.J according to the expected output yes soring on time is necessary. :) cs95 has got you covered. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can first mark the duplicate payments in your `Dollar` column. Then mark per customer if the difference is less then 2 minutes:

```
DF.sort_values(['customerID', 'transactionDateTime'], inplace=True)

m1 = DF.groupby('customerID', sort=False)['Dollar'].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())
m2 = DF.groupby('customerID', sort=False)['transactionDateTime'].diff() <= pd.Timedelta(2, unit='minutes')

DF['Duplicated?'] = np.where(m1 & m2, 'Yes', 'No')
```

---

```
   customerID  Dollar transactionDateTime Duplicated?
0         111       1 2016-01-08 19:04:50          No
1         111       1 2016-01-08 19:05:50         Yes
2         111     100 2016-01-08 20:08:50          No
3         111       3 2016-01-29 19:03:55          No
4         111     100 2016-02-08 20:08:50          No
5         222      25 2016-01-08 19:04:50          No
6         222       8 2016-02-08 19:04:50          No
7         222      25 2016-03-08 19:04:50          No
8         333       9 2016-01-08 19:02:15          No
9         333       9 2016-01-08 19:03:20         Yes
10        333       9 2016-01-08 19:04:50         Yes
11        333      20 2016-03-08 19:05:53          No
```

Answer (score 2):

I made `pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)` to compare against the `diff()`

```
m2 = pd.Timedelta(minutes=2)    
DF['dup'] = DF.sort_values('transactionDateTime').groupby(['Dollar','ID']).transactionDateTime.diff().abs().le(m2).astype(int)


Out[272]:
    Dollar   ID transactionDateTime  dup
0        1  111 2016-01-08 19:04:50    0
1        3  111 2016-01-29 19:03:55    0
2        1  111 2016-01-08 19:05:50    1
3      100  111 2016-01-08 20:08:50    0
4       25  222 2016-01-08 19:04:50    0
5        8  222 2016-02-08 19:04:50    0
6       25  222 2016-03-08 19:04:50    0
7        9  333 2016-01-08 19:04:50    1
8       20  333 2016-03-08 19:05:53    0
9        9  333 2016-01-08 19:03:20    1
10       9  333 2016-01-08 19:02:15    0
11     100  111 2016-02-08 20:08:50    0
```